# One to many relationship between owned entity and aggregate root in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Im creating an application for managing projects and stumbled upon the following problem:
I have an project aggregate which contains a list of participants of the project and their sessions. Each of the participants is referencing an Account using foreign key.

My problem is that i need to define the relationship between the account and the project as the project is not directly referencing the account.

The account <s>entity</s> aggregate (simplified):

```
public class Account
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string AccountName { get; set; }
  public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Thats the current project aggregate (simplified)

```
public class Project
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public List<Participant> Participants { get; set;}
}


public class Participant
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Account Account { get; set; }
  public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}


public class Session
{
  DateTime Start { get; set; }
  DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

The configurations are the following:

```
private void ConfigureProjectsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Project> builder)
{
  builder.ToTable("Projects");
  builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
}
private void ConfigureParticipantsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Project> builder)
{
  builder.OwnsMany(p => p.Participants, pb =>
  {
    pb.ToTable("Participants");
    pb.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ProjectId");
    pb.HasKey(nameof(Participant.Id), "ProjectId");
    
    pb.HasOne(p => p.Account)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey("AccountId");
  }
}
```

I already tried extracting the participant class into another aggregate but the project class needs to make sure that one account cannot be in one project multiple times.
I also watched some tutorials including [this](https://youtu.be/f6G46rqkePc?si=0Ois7eGXie2TCzLf&t=688) where such a situation occurs as well so this does not seem impossible.

With my current approach (leaving `WithMany()` empty) the projects table will get a foreign key to the account but thats not what i want since one project can have multiple participants. I also tried around with putting the relation to the account configuration but i have the same problem there with the `HasOne()` method.

Another idea i had was to hold the list of participants in the account class like this:

```
public class Account
{
  public List<Participant> Participates { get; set; }
}
```

Then i could access the project class by using `Participant.Project` but that does not seem to fit the concepts of DDD as I am referencing an entity directly here.

**Update**

The reference from the account class to the project class is just for reading purposes. It would be very inefficient to read all projects and join them with participants and accounts just to know in which projects the account participates.

It should also be possible to have a project without any participants and an account that participates on multiple projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The participant is owned by project and project is owned by account,. For participant to get to Account you need to go through project, anything otherwise is breaking normalization. Even without considering the owned nature of the relationship you should avoid "shortcut" references because this opens the door to invalid data combinations. Nothing enforces that a Participant's Account reference is guaranteed to match the account that it's Project is pointing to, and it should always match the project's account.

Using owned entities is nominating Account as the aggregate root. Since all owned types are accessed via their aggregate root you technically don't even need bi-directional references since you should be loading them through their aggregates. There is no Participants `DbSet`, nor can participants be shared with any other aggregate so arguably there is no need to ever go from Participant "up" to account since you should always be loading participants "through" their account. (and project)

When it comes to inserting data you don't need parent references, just associate the new owned entities through their parent and EF will work out the FK assignments. You can create participant entities and add them to a new project added to the loaded account, or add them to an existing project on the account, then EF's change tracking will apply the necessary inserts and updates to work out the FK associations. There is no need to do something like create a participant and set it's Project reference to save a new participant etc. They work top-down, not bottom up.

Hopefully that makes sense as an explanation. :)

**Edit** - Ok based on this:

> It would be very inefficient to read all projects and join them with participants and accounts just to know in which projects the account participates.

... I think I see what you are looking for. You want to easily get the participants and/or sessions for a given account without having to load the entire set of accounts.  This is where EF's navigation properties and projection can help you. For example with bi-direction references you can get participants for a given account using something like this:

```
var accountParticipants = await _context.Projects
    .Where(project => project.Account.AccountId == accountId)
    .SelectMany(project => project.Participants)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Since participants are owned by project we need to query at the project level, but tell EF that we actually want the participants. This doesn't "load" the projects, or the account, it just uses the navigation property mapping to work out how to filter down to the data we want using the FKs.

If you are at the account level and wanted to load the participants and they hadn't been eager loaded then it would be easy to load them using that same query. Lazy loading can also handle loading them, though that is considerably more expensive. Accessing the Account.Projects navigation property would trigger one SQL call to load the projects for that account, but then touching each Project.Participants navigation property would trigger another SQL call for each Project to fetch the participants. Using the above query to load from _context.Projects would be 1 hit to the database. If the account had 10 projects, lazy loading would execute 11 hits to the database. (1 for fetching the projects, and 1 to fetch participants for each of the 10 projects)

If participants weren't owned, but instead were regular associated entities with a DbSet, the query could look like this:

```
var accountParticipants = await _context.Participants
    .Where(participant => participant.Project.Account.AccountId == accountId)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Note that just because we reference the Project and then the Project's Account in the query doesn't mean these entities are loaded. The DbContext will associate tracked instances *if* they happen to already be loaded and tracked, they won't be fetched from the DB.

When it comes to reading data I recommend using projection for reads and just reserve fetching entities for things like update scenarios. For instance if you are reading a set of accounts based on a criteria and wanted a count of participants, this would be a particularly expensive query with eager loading, and disastrously expensive if it tripped lazy loading. Projection allows you to summarize the data you want back where EF can populate values from entities and their relatives rather than loading entire object graphs. For instance if we have a list of accounts to display where we need the account ID, name, and a count of participants. Using eager loading we'd write something like:

```
 var accounts = await _context.Accounts
     .Include(account => account.Projects)
         .ThenInclude(project => project.Participants)
     .Where(account => /* some criteria */)
     .ToListAsync();
```

... which would be quite expensive loading the records from account then all of the associated projects and participants. Instead with projection we declare the projection view model:

```
 public class AccountSummaryViewModel
 {
     public int AccountId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int ParticipantCount { get; set; }
 }
```

... then query to populate it.

```
 var accounts = await _context.Accounts
     .Where(account => /* some criteria */)
     .Select(account => new AccountSummaryViewModel
     {
         AccountId = account.AccountId,
         Name = account.Name,
         ParticipantCount = account.Projects
             .Sum(project => project.Paricipants.Count())
     }).ToListAsync();
```

This doesn't load all projects and participants, or even all columns from the account. It builds an SQL statement using the entity configuration to pull back just this projection that our view or code needs. This is magnitudes faster and uses a lot less memory than eager loading.

**Edit #2**: Mapping through participants. Since participant is acting essentially like a many-to-many joining table, but it also contains meaningful data, we need to map any relationship from account to project and back through participant.  If participant was just an AccountProject, we wouldn't even need to declare/use an AccountProject or Participant entity you would have Account.Projects and Project.Accounts, but participant is significant since there are also sessions associated to it so we need:

```
public class Account
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string AccountName { get; set; }
  public List<Particpant> Particpants { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public List<Participant> Participants { get; set;}
}


public class Participant
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Account Account { get; set; }
  public Project Project { get; set; } // can be optional
  public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

Now when configuring:

```
private void ConfigureProjectsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Project> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Projects");
    builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Participants)
       .WithOne(p => p.Project);
}

private void ConfigureAccountsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Account> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Accounts");
    builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Participants)
       .WithOne(p => p.Account);
}

private void ConfigureParticipantsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Project> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Participants");
    builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Sessions)
       .WithOne()
       .HasForeignKey("ParticipantId"); // Shadow property or point at a property in Session.
}
```

If you want the projects for an account you need to go through particpants:

```
var projects = _context.Accounts
    .Where(x => x.Id == accountId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Participants.Select(p => p.Project))
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var projects = _context.Projects
    .Where(x => x.Particpants.Any(p => p.Account.Id == accountId)
    .ToList();
```

When reading data and wanting to include details about relations like this I recommend using projection rather than trying to load the entire entity graph then this relation can be suitably flattened to give you something like an account with it's projects or project with its accounts. You can also opt for a convenience unmapped property in Account or Project for instance:

```
[NotMapped]
public List<Project> Projects => Participants.Select(p => p.Project).ToList();
```

However, to use such a property you would have needed to either eager load the participants and their project, or have lazy loading enabled and incur the cost of the round trip.

```
var account = await _context.Accounts
    .WHere(a => a.Id == accountId)
    .Include(a => a.Participants)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Project)
    .AsSplitQuery() // can be useful when eager loading multiple levels.
    .SingleAsync();
```

These unmapped helpers can be useful, but you need to remember that you cannot use them in Linq2SQL query expressions. So you cannot write a query like:

```
var accounts = _context.Accounts
    .Where(a => a.Projects.Any(p => p.StartDate >= startDate)
    .ToList();
```

You have to go through the mapped relationship:

```
var accounts = _context.Accounts
    .Where(a => a.Participants.Any(p => p.Project.StartDate >= startDate)
    .ToList();
```

Slightly less convenient, but you do get used to it and it keeps the data properly normalized.

Alternatively, your comment about Project having an AccountId implies that there is no need for Participant to act as a many-to-many between these tables. In this case you need to choose what Participant has a reference to, Account, or Project, not both. Either Account has Particpants or Project has Participants, but you cannot map Acount to have partipants and particpant having projects. If Account has participants and participant has an AccountID:

```
public class Account
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string AccountName { get; set; }
  public List<Particpant> Particpants { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}


public class Participant
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Account Account { get; set; }
  public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

.. and when configuring:

```
private void ConfigureProjectsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Project> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Projects");
    builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
}

private void ConfigureAccountsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Account> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Accounts");
    builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Participants)
       .WithOne(p => p.Account);
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Projects)
       .WithOne(p => p.Account);
}

private void ConfigureParticipantsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Project> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Participants");
    builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Sessions)
       .WithOne()
       .HasForeignKey("ParticipantId"); // Shadow property or point at a property in Session.
}
```

IF you want projects associated to a participant, you need to go through the account:

```
var participantProjects = _context.Participants
    .Where(p => p.Id == participantId)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Account.Projects)
    .ToList();
```

Similarly you can use an unmapped property in participant:

```
[NotMapped]
public List<Project> Projects => Account.SelectMany(a => a.Projects).ToList();
```

... with the same restrictions on use.

Now this assumes that an account has many participants and participants belong to a single account, meaning the Participants tale contains an AccountId. If participants can belong to multiple accounts then you would need a many-to-many linking table for AccountParticipants.

Comment: Thanks to your response but I dont think that using the Account as an aggregate root is usefull here. It has to be possible to create a project without having any accounts in the system as they are accounts are joining the project after it has been created.Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Ah, if the Account-Project relationship isn't owned, that is fine. I misread the configuration.  However the base issue is still introducing that shortcut navigation property from participant to account. Participants will always be fetched with their project and should always have the same account and their project. As an owned relationship you cannot read a participant without it's project, so participants will always access the correct account info through their project.

Comment: Exactly and thats why i want to store a list of projects in the account class so I dont need a direct reference to the participant. But i dont know how to populate this list from the participant class.

Comment: I have updated the answer which what it looks like you are looking for. Referencing data through navigation properties within query expressions does not mean those entities get read so you can fetch related entities either down or up reference chains as needed. For read operations I recommend using projection to select/summarize info to avoid the cost of loading entire entity graphs for more selective information through the relationships.

Comment: Ok thank you that was really helpful! But i still have one problem: ef core keeps generating an accountId foreign key on the projects table - which it should not do as the reference is set on the participant entity. How do i configure this kind of relation properly?

Comment: If an account has a collection of  projects, then the Account ID needs to be on Project. Otherwise an Account would need to instead have a collection of Participants, and you would get to project via the participant.

Comment: Ah I Inderstand. So if Projects - Accounts ist a many to many i would need a Relationsship Table right? But wouldnt this be redundant Seen from the Database layer AS the participant already hast the Project and the Account id?

Comment: Yes, the participant acts as a many-to-many the way you have the relationships set up, because it's not a basic many-to-many join (which would contain just the FK fields, not other data like Sessions etc.) you cannot shortcut the collection from account-> Projects. When the joining table is just AId, BId, then you can have A.Bs and B.As, but when the joining table has more significance it needs to be A.ABs.B and B.ABs.A if that makes sense. Account to get projects has to be through participants, and the same for Project to Account. Any shortcut would need to be unmapped.

Comment: I get what you mean but im still confused on how to configure the relationship with fluent api. I need to reference the Account by doing `builder.HasOne(participant => participant.Id)` and as you mentioned I cannot reference the Project from the Account directly so i dont want this kind of navigation. But what is the correct way of configuring this in fluent api? I always get the AccountId in the project table even it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ok, added Edit #2 which outlines the relationship and how it would be mapped and queried which will hopefully help, If you have/want an  AccountId on your Project table then It does sound like you need to revisit the relationship between these three tables. If a project only apples to a single account then participant should not tie *both* entities,  The edit covers this scenario as well. You may be mixing relations between many-to-many and one-to-many which won't work the way you might expect, not just from EF but DB normalization.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I didnt know its not possible to have this kind of relation when using owned entities. Your example is basically what I needed to do and as you already said I need to rethink the overall structure a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Steve Py , since account is the aggregate root, when an external object needs to access an entity inside an aggregate, it should only be accessible through the aggregate root.

Meanwhile, accourding to your project logic, Account is many-to-many with Project, and Participant is one-to-one with Account. Many-to-many means one project can have several distinct accounts and one account can have several distinct projects. So your design can be modified.

> Account one-to-one Participant

> Account many-to-many Project

Then your model can be modified this way

```
public class Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public Participant? Part { get; set; }
}

public class Participant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }  // Required foreign key property
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    DateTime Start { get; set; }
    DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

And to make it clear to understand, though unnecessary, you can add the relationship in your context configuration

```
//Configure many-to-many relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Projects)
    .WithMany(e => e.Accounts)
    .UsingEntity(
        "AccountProject",
        l => l.HasOne(typeof(Project)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("ProjectsId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Project.Id)),
        r => r.HasOne(typeof(Account)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("AccountsId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Account.Id)),
        j => j.HasKey("AccountsId", "ProjectsId")); ;

//Configure one-to-one relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Part)
    .WithOne(e => e.Account)
    .HasForeignKey<Participant>(e => e.AccountId)
    .IsRequired();
```

Test

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but the account is not the aggregate root, its another aggregate that should reference the projects aggregate. Also Account is not one to one to Participant as one account can participate in multiple projects. The list of projects in the accounts table is just for reading purposes. It would be very inefficient to get all projects and to join them with participants and players just to know in which projects the player participated.